# Website session automatically timeout after a while due to inactivity using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

This never happened before, anyways to solve it?
My 2 cents for potentially solving this problem:

1. create activity: tried to refresh the webpage, doesn't work.
2. probably there's a timer in the session or browser that I don't know exists so i can modify it somehow.

Inputs are welcomed!!!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k0Qn.png)

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ok, I just tried to see if there's any problem with cookies. When I use this:         self.driver.delete_all_cookies(), the browser will automatically log me out.

Comment: This feature is implemented through the application rules, what exactly do you want to achieve through Selenium?

Comment: So here it is, the website needs me to log in to book a slot, and people sometimes discard their slots, so whoever's the fastest gets it. I'm running my program in loops to find it via selenium. However, this is the first time I encounter this inactivity thing. So basically every 20mins of running, I am automatically logged off due to inactivity, but actually my program runs the whole time. pressing on buttons n such. I have no idea how to come around it. And I am not able to auto login again due to the stupid captcha thing.